# c# PowerShell Sharepoint invoke timerjob

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, powershell

I am trying to invoke a `SPTimerJob` to run on demand. What I'm trying to do, is to call `Word Automation Services` to convert my word files.

So far I have tried our different solutions and none of them seems to be working.

I know, that working command would be `Start-SPTimerJob "Word Automation Services"`. When I run that command from PowerShell it self, then it works like a charm, but when I try to call it with the following code, it seems to have no effect:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddScript("Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell");
            ps.AddScript("Start-SPTimerJob 'Word Automation Services'");
            ps.Invoke();
         });
```

I appreciate all the help! :)

EDIT:

I have tried few different approaches, and I get `The method or operation is not implemented` exception.

example:

```
SPSite spSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
            foreach (var service in spSite.WebApplication.Farm.Services)
            {
                if (service.TypeName == "Word Automation Services")
                {
                    foreach (var jobDefinition in service.JobDefinitions)
                    {
                        if (jobDefinition.Name == "Word Automation Services")
                        {
                            //jobDefinition.RunNow();
                            jobDefinition.Execute(Guid.Empty);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

With Akhoy code:

```
SPService s = SPFarm.Local.Services.FirstOrDefault(s1 => s1.TypeName.Equals("Word Automation Services"));
            foreach (SPJobDefinition job in s.JobDefinitions)
            {
                if (job.DisplayName.Equals("Word Automation Services Timer Job"))
                {
                    job.Execute(jobGuid);
                }
            }
```

But I get following exception (tried with `Guid.Empty` and current Guid on the picture is from `ConversionJob.JobId`:
[image: notImplementedException]

Comment: Change `Execute` to `RunNow()`. It works fine for me. Check update.

Comment: Currently trying out solution with `RunNow()`, but I have some Security issues with that `System.Security.SecurityException: Access denied.`. Tells me to edit my application's trust level in configuration file, not sure, why this problem occurs, but trying to figure it out.

Comment: You need to be a farm admin to run that.

Comment: Doesn't `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate(){   });` do that trick?

Comment: No. It runs under app pool account not farm admin account. Also, see if this helps. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/05003179-6b4d-410a-b487-ecc8d27caf85/spjobdefinition-runnow-method-access-denied. But if your app pool account and farm account is the same, then RWEP might work.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will go easier way at this point (setting job interval to 1 min) and will look into this problem in the future at some point. I hope, someone else finds this helpful as well :)

Comment: Glad i could help :) so I'm assuming it worked. So how did it work finally? You ran this as a farm admin?

Comment: As I said on previous comment, I went easier way at the moment, there might be some problems with my test environment, since I should have all the rights in there. But I'll keep that solution in mind and look into it at some later point! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint timer service (OWSTIMER.exe) which handles the running of timer jobs runs under farm account credentials. Running it under application pool account wouldn't work.

And there's no need to use PowerShell to start a timer job if you're using C# since there are server side API's which let you do the same thing.

```
SPService s = SPFarm.Local.Services.FirstOrDefault(s1 => s1.TypeName.Equals("Word Automation Services"));
foreach (SPJobDefinition job in s.JobDefinitions)
                {
                    if (job.DisplayName.Equals("Word Automation Services Timer Job"))
                    {
                        job.RunNow();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I get `The method or operation is not implemented` exception, when i try to execute this command. Since, I can't find "Word Automation Services", I am using "Document Conversions" instead.

Comment: You'll have to enter the correct timer job name. For me, Word Automation Services display name is showing as "Word Automation Services Timer Job".

Comment: It's weird, since, when I run "Word Automation Services" under PowerShell, then it works like a charm, but I can't find that job or anything close to it under `spSite.WebApplication.JobDefinitons`.

Comment: Updated code. Tested this. This seems to work fine.